# State change not reflecting on the UI of child component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have two component **FirstParent** and **SecondParent** both of them have the same child component **Child**.

If I click on the Icon when in **FirstParent**, the state (redux) gets updated and the UI reflects the value of Text as 20.

But If I do the same from **SecondParent**, only the state (redux) gets updated but the UI doesn't display the value of Text as 20.

What am I missing here?

**FirstParentComponent**

```
handleRender = ({ item }) => {
  // some code here
  return (
    <Child foo={item} />
  )
}

render() {
  <FlatList
    renderItem={this.handleRender}
    // other attributes
  />
}
```

**SecondParentComponent**

```
render() {
  const { item } = this.props;

  // some code here
  <Child foo={item} />
}

// some code here
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => (
  const item = state.data.find(
    foo => foo.id === ownProps.navigation.getParam('foo', {}).id)
  )
 return { item };
);
```

**ChildComponent**

```
updateFoo = (id, value) => {
  const { updateReduxState} = this.props;

  // some code here
  updateReduxState({ id, value })
}

render() {
  const { foo: { id, value} } = this.props;

  // some code here
  <Icon onPress={() => { this.updateFoo(id, 20); }}
  <Text>{value}</Text>
}

// some code here
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators(
      { updateReduxState: updateValue},
       dispatch,
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the second component to reflect the change in state by shifting things around. But i'm still not satisfied since now i have to iterate over the state to retrieve the item.

**FirstParentComponent**

```
handleRender = ({ item }) => {
  // some code here
  return (
    <Child fooId={item.id} />
  )
}

render() {
  <FlatList
    renderItem={this.handleRender}
    // other attributes
  />
}
```

**SecondParentComponent**

```
render() {
  const { itemId } = this.props;

  // some code here
  <Child fooId={itemId} />
}
```

**ChildComponent**

```
updateFoo = (id, value) => {
  const { updateReduxState} = this.props;

  // some code here
  updateReduxState({ id, value })
}

render() {
  const { foo: { id, value} } = this.props;

  // some code here
  <Icon onPress={() => { this.updateFoo(id, 20); }}
  <Text>{value}</Text>
}

// some code here
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => (
  const foo = state.data.find(
    foo => foo.id === ownProps.fooId)
  )
 return { foo };
);

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => (
  bindActionCreators(
      { updateReduxState: updateValue},
       dispatch,
    )
  )
);
```